# excel time less than 3 hours conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

i want to have a check on cells if=C2-B2<3 and if the difference is less than 3:00:00 that cell A2 is filled colour red.
So far i figured out that =ABS($C$2-$B$2)*24<3 works sorta, but when the time is after midnight it doesn't work, for example 23:30 to 3:30 does nothing

1. How can i fix this?
2. how can i make this work from range A1 to H3, without having to make a separate formula per column?

   ```
   Monday      start   end     x   Teusday     start   end     x
   5/3/2021    19:30   23:30   x   5/4/2021    23:30   3:35    x
   5/3/2021    23:30   3:30    x   5/4/2021    23:30   2:30    x
   5/3/2021    23:30   3:00    x   5/4/2021    23:30   2:30    x
   ```

regards,
Kiewan

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=IF(C2>B2,C2-B2,1-B2+C2)<3/24
```

time arithmetic in excel is very tricky. A good explanation can be found here:

https://exceljet.net/formula/calculate-number-of-hours-between-two-times

Comment: Hi Jayvee, that worked like a charm.

Just one more follow up question which i forgot to add.
There is also a break that needs to be calculated, how would the formula look like including the break?

for example below 19:30 to 22:30 is 3:00, but minus the break it comes down to 2:55 worked.

`Monday      start     end     break  Teusday    start    end      break`
`5/3/2021    19:30   22:30  00:05   5/4/2021    23:30   3:35    00:07`

Comment: @KiewanSanee time in excel works in fractions of a day. So as there are 1440 minutes in a day, five minutes equates to 5/1440. Suppose break is in column D then the formula would be =IF(C2>B2,C2-B2,1-B2+C2)-D2/1440<3/24